# How often can/should an adrequest be used?

Tags: java, android, admob

In my app I have a banner(`AdView`) and an interstitial which both load their respective ads from the same `adRequest` Object. Or at least the initial Ad in the case of the interstitial. Which is working and at least for TestAds it isn't the same one. Is this good practice or should I build a new AdRequest Object for each individual Ad? Also is it possible to specify what type of Ad the request is requesting?

Here's the code where I request and load the ads:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    AdView banner = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitialAdId));

    createAdRequest();

    banner.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            createAdRequest();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
}

private void createAdRequest() {
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you dont need more ad requests, actually the adrequest object doesnt have ad specific information, this means you can use one ad request for multiple ads and ad types it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create AdRequest for every new Ads as you are doing but as you send request is not valid( from ad close listener).

Comment: what do you mean by send request is not valid?

Comment: As per documentation you have to send request at specific interval not from AdClose listener

Comment: could you provide me the link to the part of the documentation that this is mentioned? I didn't see anything like this mentioned in the documentation

Comment: see this, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial  -->Just as it's important to make sure you display interstitial ads at an appropriate time

Comment: at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#using_an_adlistener_to_reload it states: "The AdListener class's onAdClosed() method is a handy place to load a new interstitial after displaying the previous one"